# HTML5 Import with dynamically created link

Tags: javascript, html, html5-import

I'm trying to understand, why HTML5 Import doesn't work with dynamically created `link` element.

**First example.** It's work fine.

main_page.html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="import.html">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var imported = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
        var el = imported.querySelector('#foo');
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    </script>
</body>
```

import.html:

```
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

**Second example.** For some reason, it doesn't work.

main_page.html:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'import';
        link.href = 'import.html';
        document.head.appendChild(link);

        var imported = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
        var el = imported.querySelector('#foo');
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    </script>
</body>
```

import.html:

```
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

Why it occurs and how it may be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would happen because the `link` is not yet loaded when you are calling `querySelector('link[rel="import"]')`.

One way to fix it would be to run the subsequent code when the link is loaded using `link.onload`. You can even save that `querySelector` call, which should make it a bit faster:

```
 var loadFoo = function(event) {
   var imported = event.target.import;
   var el = imported.querySelector('#foo');
   document.body.appendChild(el);
 }

 var link = document.createElement('link');
 link.rel = 'import';
 link.href = 'import.html';
 link.onload = loadFoo;
 document.head.appendChild(link);
```

You could (and probably should) add an `onerror` handler to run when things go wrong.

Comment: Thank you :-) It works. Could you elaborate, what are another ways to fix it? I'm asking just out of curiosity, for my further self-education.

Comment: ES6 Promises. But it seems like overkill for a single link. See this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises (it's about images, but link works more or less the same way).